# Use SwaggerUI to authenticate against IdentiyServer 4 with own protected API Endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, identityserver4, swagger-ui

I'm relatively new to IdentityServer4 but I went through the docs and managed to set it up.

In my scenario I want to use IdentityServer4 and also protect additional endpoints within the identity server. I followed the documentation to use client credentials as described [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html). Instead of using a separate API I followed the docs [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html) to protect the API endpoints within the identity server which works as expected.

I also want to use Swagger to provide documentation for these additional endpoints. But unfortunately I don't know how to properly setup the configuration. The "Authorize" button appears and I can enter the client and secret and also login which works fine but whenever I try to execute the action with Swagger I get a 401 Unauthorized error back.

My sample project looks like this:

Program.cs

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                // uncomment to write to Azure diagnostics stream
                //.WriteTo.File(
                //    @"D:\home\LogFiles\Application\identityserver.txt",
                //    fileSizeLimitBytes: 1_000_000,
                //    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                //    shared: true,
                //    flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting host...");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly.");
                return 1;
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .AddControllers();

            services
                .AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
                    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients);

            services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "Protected API", Version = "v1"});
    
                options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        ClientCredentials = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/connect/authorize"),
                            TokenUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/connect/token"),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                {"IdentityServerApi", "Demo API - full access"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");

                options.OAuthClientId("client");
                options.OAuthAppName("Demo API - Swagger");
                options.OAuthUsePkce();
            });
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers()
                    .RequireAuthorization(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.PolicyName); // auth attribute for all controllers!
            });
        }
    }
```

Config.cs

```
public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId()
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new List<ApiScope>
            {
                new ApiScope(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName, "My API"),
            };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "client",

                    // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

                    // secret for authentication
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },

                    // scopes that client has access to
                    AllowedScopes = { IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName }
                }
            };
    }
```

LocalApiController.cs

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("localApi")]
    public class LocalApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Get()
        {
            return Ok("ok");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check if the authorization header is being sent successfully with the swagger requests?

Comment: @PlamenYordanov

Request Headers:
:authority: localhost:5001
:method: GET
:path: /localApi
:scheme: https
accept: text/plain
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36

Sorry for the bad formatting :-/

Comment: Can you post your /swagger/v1/swagger.json json file as the Authorization header is missing from the request and I'm thinking that the operation is currently defined not to require authorization.

Comment: You are my hero! thank you so much!

I added the authorize Attribute and added the filter like it is definied here: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/ASPNET-Core-Swagger-UI-Authorization-using-IdentityServer4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add authentication information to the swagger documentation.

After adding the following filter and registering it like described [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/ASPNET-Core-Swagger-UI-Authorization-using-IdentityServer4) everything works

```
public class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var hasAuthorize = 
          context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any() 
          || context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any();

        if (hasAuthorize)
        {
            operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorized" });
            operation.Responses.Add("403", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Forbidden" });

            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    [
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme {Reference = new OpenApiReference 
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, 
                            Id = "oauth2"}
                        }
                    ] = new[] {"api1"}
                }
            };

        }
    }
}
```